# incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending viewcontroller * to parameter of type BOOL

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I was trying to work out how to read a text file stored on a web server and display the contents in a text view. I have followed the documentation from Apple website [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) of how to establish a NSURLConnection and receiveData and display the received data.

I have created a button where I want to load the text view on button click. For that I wrote this method

```
- (void)loadWeb:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nowayweb.com/mytext.txt"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (myConnection) {
        downloadedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
}
```

But I am getting a warning in my .m file which can be seen in the screenshot as shown here:
[image: Warning Screenshot]

It works fine and I can view the text in the text view, but I am wondering where am I making the mistake. If somebody throws some light on this, would be helpful.

Or is there a better way to load the contents from web by button click. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is a pointer to an object, not a BOOL value.  You should do this:

```
[self loadWeb: YES];
```

Except your method does not seem to use the parameter anyway, so you might as well get rid of it.

```
[self loadWeb];
```

and

```
- (void)loadWeb
{
    // all the stuff inside
}
```

The reason it worked for you is a) you weren't using the parameter, b) the compiler will automatically convert `self` into a BOOL by chopping off all but the least significant byte of the pointer.  If you had been using the parameter, most of the time it would have been `YES` by chance and occasionally it would have been `NO` by chance.

Comment: thanks Jeremy, looked simple, but was informative, accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

ObjC's `BOOL` is not a real boolean type. it is a typedef for a `signed char`.

The method's signature is:

```
- (void)loadWeb:(BOOL)animated
```

the expression `[self loadWeb:self];` doesn't make sense, and it's not a real `bool` conversion. the compiler warns you that you are converting a pointer to a `signed char`.

It should read either:

```
[self loadWeb:YES];
```

-or-

```
[self loadWeb:NO];
```

-or-

```
BOOL someBOOLVariableOrParameter = ...; // YES or NO
[self loadWeb:someBOOLVariableOrParameter];
```